# Zoom issue on Firefox on Android when putting the device in portrait mode from landscape mode

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web

### What happens?

A zoom is applied when none is requested.

[image]

### Environment

Firefox 68.0 on Android 9 using the mobile-web version of Stack Overflow

### Steps to reproduce

1. Open Stack Overflow in Firefox
2. Tilt the device so that it's in landscape mode.
3. Tilt the device so that it's in portrait mode.

The website has now zoomed in by a factor 2 to 3.

Repeat steps 2 and 3 for further zoom.

It is possible to dezoom naturally by using fingers to go to the normal size.

### Notes

This is local to Stack Overflow: no other website I use has the same behavior.

To give a timeframe, I noticed this first roughly a week ago, maybe more, maybe less.

Comment: Could you try to see if the issue is also persistent when you switch to full-site, and potentially to the responsive version (also found in the footer)? I can't repro on Chrome fwiw.

Comment: @Luuklag I can reproduce when I click on "Full site", but cannot reproduce when I click "Disable responsiveness"?

Answer (score 2):

This is very probably a bug in Firefox for Android.

The culprit is the meta tag

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

A StackSnippet would be useless since the parent page is reproducing the issue, 
but [here is a plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/x9l4cYb4qW7f6TlU). Run it as a "separate window".

---

The [latest Nigthly version (68.1a1)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.fennec_aurora) has it fixed.

Thus, I'd say it's probably not worth a change from StackExchange.

Comment: Indeed this plunker thingy reproduces the issue and the HTML code seems rather light, hence possibly a Firefox issue. However where do you see in any release notes that the issue is fixed in the latest nightly version? I can't find those release notes anywhere...

Comment: I simply tried ;-)

Comment: And I guess it's the issue that caused the fix: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1498729

Comment: Thank you very much, it's pretty much appreciated! I haven't tested in Nightly: I'm kind of afraid of the potential of crashes in nightly versions.